# Floating a block to the right then take full width after float

Tags: html, css

I've got the following situation where I'd like the list on the right to use just the remaining space until it's passed the content on the left at which point it can take up the full width again.

I can get it done by hardcoding a `margin-left: 50%` for the first few `<li>` but this is inadequate since I don't know the text-wrapping div's dimensions.

```css
.intro {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

li {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">Some text and stuff and text and maybe some more text and donuts let's play high powered god mutant prototype<br>Some more text to illustrate obviouslycate some wrapping</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: what about browser support? can u use flexbox?

Comment: @knitevision Flexbox would be a last resort solution. Unfortunately IE9 is still in the game.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am assuming that you want the content of list items to be next to the floated content.  You can accomplish this by using regular `div`s.  Not sure as to why you are utilizing `ul` and `li` tags.

FAUX Solution:

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jebgerp8/.

HTML:

```
<div class="intro">
    Some text and stuff and text and maybe some more text and donuts let's play high powered god mutant prototype<br>Some more text to illustrate obviouslycate some wrapping
    </div>
<div class = "li">
    <img src = "http://placehold.it/50x50" />
</div>
<div class = "li">
    <img src = "http://placehold.it/50x50/ff0000" />
</div>
<div class = "li">Another "list item"</div>
<div class = "li">Fourth "list item"</div>
<div class = "li">Last "list item"</div>
```

CSS:

```
.intro {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
}

.li {
    height: 50px;
    margin: 2px 0;
}

.li:nth-last-of-type(-n + 3) {
    border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

TRUE Adjustable Solution via Flexbox (requires modern browser).

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/148y1b18/

CSS:

```
.intro {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
    border: 2px dashed #bbb;
}

.li {
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.li + .li {
    margin-top: 2px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't solve the issue. In your example you use images for the first two item so it doesn't show how the item is still "under" the float: http://jsfiddle.net/jebgerp8/1/

Comment: That was actually the point.  Of course, if you want for divs to fill exactly the space to the right of floated box, then the only way I know how to do it is to use flexbox, which does require a modern browser.  See my updated post and here is a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/148y1b18/.  Cheers.

Comment: Seems like a pure CSS solution is only achievable with flexbox. Cheers for the input.

Comment: Unfortunately there are no solid polyfills for the latest flexbox spec.  Perhaps flexie.js can be used to wrangle out the desired functionality in the older browsers using older flexbox declarations.  Cheers.

Comment: Thanks, I ended up just using flexbox and have ie 9 fallback to simple floats. Graceful'ish degradation.

Answer (score 0):

add this:

```
.list {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
```

Demonstration:

```css
.intro {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}

.list {
  width:50%;
  float:right;
}

li {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="intro">Some text and stuff and text and maybe some more text and donuts let's play high powered god mutant prototype<br>Some more text to illustrate obviouslycate some wrapping</div>
<div class="list">
    <ul>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
        <li></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Christopher but I need the list items that are below the text to take the full width of the page.

Comment: oh I see. I misunderstood that part at first but now I understand. Good luck finding an answer; i'll try to think of one.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you were trying to do with the black border but if I have a little more information I could probably help out with that a bit more too.

Part of the problem you had with the list was that you left out your . in front of the li. Look at your css above. It was not taking on the elements that you had specified.

check out this js fiddle. I think it's what you are looking for, short of the border probably.

http://jsfiddle.net/j9pekyje/

```
<p class="intro">Some text and stuff and text and maybe some more text and donuts let's play high powered god mutant prototype<br>Some more text to illustrate obviouslycate some wrapping</p>

        <ul>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
            <li>hi i like pancakes</li>
        </ul>

.intro {
    width: 50%;
    float: left;
}
.list {
    width:50%;
    float:right;
}
.li {
    display: block;
    height: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

Just a heads up on this as well. You could potentially run into some issues with total being 100% with or without setting margin or padding because that is usually additive. Something to be aware of in the future. Hope this helps you.

Comment: Leaving the `.` out is correct. `.li` references the class `li` whilst without the `.` it references the `<li>` DOM element.